# Writing a function to loop through multiple directories when the changing parameter is not at the end of the directory structure

Tags: loops, libraries

I have five years of data I need to loop through, to create 5 separate datasets. I'm trying to use a        function to do this,
to select each year, the path, and the options for selection within each year.

I tried this (after linking to a SAS session using saspy):

```
def my_read(yr_list, path, options):
result_dict={}
for yr in yr_list:`your text`

    sas.saslib(‘N' + str(yr), path, options)

filtering required data elements and subsetting records from each table over five years: 
result_dict[yr] = sas.sasdata(table=’A', libref='N' + str(yr), dsopts=options)
return result_dict

setting the parameters:
my_yr_ls = [18,19,20,21,22]
my_path=sas.saslib('Nlib',path=r"G:\D\P\N\20yr\nextleveldown\")
my_options = {
       'keep': 'A F S SP AM', # filter by name of the required columns
        'where' : 'A = "E" ' # filter by value of the rows in the selected columns

     }

call the function:
my_read(yr_list= my_yr_ls,path=my_path, options= my_options)
```

'''My problem is the use of 'yr' in the pathname, as I get this message:

```
libname nlib    'G:\D\P\N\20yr\nextleveldown'  ;
NOTE: Library NLIB does not exist.

which.... of course it doesn't, because the libraries are named as:

'G:\D\P\N\2018\nextleveldown'
'G:\D\P\N\2019\nextleveldown'
'G:\D\P\N\2020\nextleveldown'
'G:\D\P\N\2021\nextleveldown'
'G:\D\P\N\2022\nextleveldown'


I also tried curly brackets around the yr ({yr}) but got the same message.
```

Is there a way to structure the libname call so that it reads through the 5 years?
I may be trying to force  SAS methods where I shouldn't be. I need something that will work like '&yr.'               Thanks!'''

Comment: You seem to be using YR to define the libref, but I don't see where you are attempting to use YR to define the PATH you are pointing the libref towards.

Comment: Hmm.. ok. Where would I use that in my code? Thx!

Comment: Don't know that language (is it python?) but since you used `'N' + str(yr)` why not use , `'G:\D\P\N\' + str(yr) + '\nextleveldown'` ?